# how to write name_mapping.csv file in volttron weather Agent ? or Syntax of name_mapping.csv. I'm trying to write name_mapping for OpenWeatherApi

Tags: volttron

What is syntax of name_mapping.csv file for OpenWeather Api.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Ocz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The name mapping comes from a standard http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-standard-names/57/build/cf-standard-name-table.html.  The mapping allows the user to focus on the standard while the different services can choose to name things differently.

Please see https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/developing-volttron/developing-agents/specifications/weather-service.html?highlight=weather%20agent